# Android Webview Zoom Density

Tags: android, webview

I would like to set the zoomlevel on my WebView (WebChromeClient).

According to the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.ZoomDensity.html) WebSettings holds a static method ZoomDensity that should do the trick but I just can't make it work. It looks like WebSettings does not have the method, Content Assistant does not suggest it or show it to me..

Neither the Webview or the WebSettings hold any other method to set the zoomlevel - so I'm stuck.

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - the answer to the problem was that I ran the application for Android version 3 - and not 7.

Simple errors always takes the longest time to find out ;)